# Flask Python Model Validation

Tags: python, validation, flask

Coming from a php background, I am learning python through Flask. I have used WTForms for the client, and this handles validation nicely.

However, one of the things that I would like to use flask for is a public API, in which case I would like all validation to be run on my models. I thought that SQLAlchemy would include validation functionality, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

I have come across [Colander](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/index.html), which looks nice, but I am kinda surprised that there are not more ubiquitous validation libraries. And even more surprised that SQLAlchemy doesn't do this natively.

What are the options here? Perhaps I am missing something, but how can I easily validate model data?

Answer (score 26):

### Have you considered doing the validation in the Model layer...

This would allow you to have a perfectly DRY solution as validation would be automatically triggered whether the update source is data sent by the user, or whether it is a component of your application which is updating the model as part of an indirect update. In short, you could also reuse this solution in your front-end with WTForms, and have only one place where you do your validation for both your API and your front-end.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5305920/2274357) for more pros of doing the validation in the model.

---

### ...using tools provided by SQLAlchemy?

#### 1. [The `validates()` decorator](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_attributes.html#sqlalchemy.orm.validates) for simple validation:

Using this decorator is pretty straightforward: just apply it to the fields you want to validate:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import validates

class EmailAddress(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'address'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String)

    @validates('email')
    def validate_email(self, key, address):
        assert '@' in address
        return address
```

#### 2. [ORM Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html?highlight=orm%20events#orm-events) for complex business rules:

You can use attribute events to perform complex validation directly when one of the attributes of an instance of a model is changed. The advantage of using attribute events is that you are guaranteed that the data in the session (the objects in-memory) are in a validated state.

Here is an example (*a simple one*, but you should think complex rules here) from the [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html?highlight=orm%20events#attribute-events):

```
def validate_phone(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    "Strip non-numeric characters from a phone number"

    return re.sub(r'(?![0-9])', '', value)

# setup listener on UserContact.phone attribute, instructing
# it to use the return value
listen(UserContact.phone, 'set', validate_phone, retval=True)
```

You could also use Mapper Events such as [`before_insert`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html?highlight=orm%20events#sqlalchemy.orm.events.MapperEvents.before_insert) to postpone validation to the `session.add()` call, or even use [Session Events](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html?highlight=orm%20events#session-events) to intercept commits... But  you lose the integrity guarantee of the data *in the session*...

Answer (score 8):

I'm writing a library for this, called [Flask-Inputs](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Inputs/).

Similar to Colander, you define schemas and validate your inputs against them. Like @Sean Vieira's suggestion, it relies on WTForms for validation.

Internally, it converts all `request` input data to MultiDicts. Just like WTForms, you can define custom validators (one built-in custom validator is for `request.json` data, it uses jsonschema for validation).

Since it sounds like you're running validation on data posted to a public API, here's an example for API key and posted JSON validation.

```
from flask_inputs import Inputs
from flask_inputs.validators import JsonSchema

schema = {
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
        'name': {'type': 'string'}
    }
}

class ApiInputs(Inputs):
    headers = {
        'Authorization': [DataRequired(), valid_api_key]
    }
    json = [JsonSchema(schema=schema)]
```

Then in your route:

```
@app.route('/api/<version>/endpoint')
def endpoint():
    inputs = ApiInputs(request)

    if not inputs.validate():
        return jsonify(success=False, errors=inputs.errors)
```

The biggest benefits I've found (using it in production) is surfacing all errors in one place. Good validators covering all incoming data prevent a lot of unexpected/undefined behavior in production.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the data coming in can be read in a Multi-Dict like format there is no reason why you can't still use WTForms for the validation (albeit, it is a little more awkward than using Colander).

So for a hypothetical API that produces and consumes JSON you might do something like this:

```
class MyDataStructure(Form):
    widget = TextField("Widget", validators=[Required()])
    quantity = IntegerField("Quantity", validators=[Required()])

@app.route("/api/v1/widgets", methods=["POST"])
def widgets():
    try:
        new_widget_info = json.loads(request.form.data)
    except KeyError:
        return jsonify(error="Must provide widget JSON in data param")
    except ValueError:
        return jsonify(error="Invalid JSON Provided")

    data = MyDataStructure(**new_widget_info)
    if not data.validate():
        return jsonify(error="Missing or invalid data",
                           error_details=data.errors)
    else:
        # Create a new widget
```