# SqlAlchemy Flask model restrict save - relationship configuration

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have two models (I am using MySQL.):

```
class Customer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'customer'
   ...
   partner_id =Column(Integer, ForeignKey('partner.id'), nullable=False) 
   ...

class User(Base):
  ...
  customer_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('customer.id'), nullable=False)
  partner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('partner.id'), nullable=False)
  ...
```

How can I check while the save of a `User` with a `customer_id` and `partner_id` that the `partner_id` corresponds to that of the `Customer` with the `customer_id`?
Are there any relationship configuration to prohibit that ? 
I tried :

```
ForeignKeyConstraint(['partner_id'], ['customer.partner_id'])
```

at the User model but it doesn't stop when I try otherwise!

Comment: "check while the save of a User with a customer_id and partner_id that the partner_id corresponds to that of the Customer with the customer_id". It could just be me but this statement is very confusing and hard to understand what you are asking for. You might want to try using an example in your question ?

Comment: I want to save a user. Now the User table has a FK to Customer and Partner. The Customer table has a FK to Partner. Now while saving a User, if I save with a Customer whose FK; partner_id=1 (from Customer Table), the partner_id in User table needs to be 1. It needs to throw an error if some other value is tried to put in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was kind of asking for the thing in this. Thanks to [edsioufi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2274357/edsioufi)

[Flask Python Model Validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582233/flask-python-model-validation)

Answer (score 0):

I guess maybe I have caught your point.

You could do the validation or constraint with some codes like this:

```
user = user_to_save()
customer = session.query(Customer).filter(Customer.id = user.customer_id).one()
if customer.partner_id == user.partner_id:
    save_user()
else:
    do_something()
```

Comment: I was wondering if SQLAlchemy itself has some methods to perform this ?